# BehaviorSubject not updating variable

Tags: angular, ionic4, behaviorsubject

I've searched google and even StackOverflow for a solution, and even tried a lot of solutions, but none of them seem to work. Here's my issue...

An Ionic 4 project: A parent component contains a header component and a content component. The header calls a behaviorsubject service to set a variable, and the content component displays the variable. This isn't working (changing the variable via the header doesn't update the variable in the content).

The filter service...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
  private filter:BehaviorSubject<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.filter = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  }
  
  setFilter(flt: string): void
  {
    this.filter.next(flt);
    console.log('filter set to ', flt);
  }

  getFilter()
  {
    return this.filter.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The header code ...

```
// ... other stuff
import { FilterService } from '@app/services/filter/filter.service';
  constructor(
    private filterService: FilterService) { }

// Called when you set the value of the variable
  filter(flt: string)
  {
    this.filterService.setFilter(flt);
console.log(flt);
  }
```

the content file

```
import { FilterService } from '@app/services/filter/filter.service';
// ... other stuff

  public thefilter = '';

constructor(
    private filterService: FilterService){}

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.filterService.getFilter().subscribe((val)=>{this.thefilter=val});
// this.thefilter doesn't update. Why???
// ...
```

I've spent days on this, to no avail! Any suggestions?

Comment: I've recreated your code and it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sijxze
 Can you take my sample and try to recreate the bug?

Comment: Thanks, it works fine if called from the same file. In my case, the header is a component, and the content another component. I call setFilter() in the header, and call getFilter() in the content, and it's not showing the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you'll need to pipe that observable. The OnDestroy manages the subscription.

This is very similar to the View Facades + RxJS pattern: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-you-may-not-need-ngrx-e80546cc56ee

Here is an example of the rxjs facade pattern in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/facades-with-rxjs-only

```
export class MyClass implements OnDestroy
  public thefilter = '';
  private onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

constructor(
  private filterService: FilterService){}

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.filterService.getFilter().pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy)).subscribe((val)=>{this.thefilter=val});


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
    this.onDestroy.complete();
  }
```